# how to inject platform id in static method in angular

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to inject platfromid to check whether the platform is a browser or server. here I have to inject the platfromid in my static method to compare the platform the code is executing. anyone has a solution. to implement this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your static method in a static class?

Comment: no it is not static a class

Comment: When will you do the injection? During the build process?

Comment: no, I don't need it while build process but I need it while running in browser or server. i need at runtime

Comment: do u have any solution to inject

Comment: What is the platfromid exactly? Where does it come from?

Comment: Why do you want a static method if the class is not static? Just declare your class as a service and inject it. Otherwise, inject the platform in `AppModule` and call a static setter function on that class to set it

Comment: like this, we are injecting the platformid in constructer but I need the same inside method @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private paltformId

Comment: i am using ngrx store and angular universal too but state management code is written in static method

Comment: i need to use platform id inside state management code

Comment: @David can u give your skype id i will explain the issue more detail

Comment: Sorry, I just help on SO. Show how/where the method is declared